# How to refresh listbox to bottom seamlessly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

I will try my best to explain. I am trying to create a IM chat app and the below codes will refresh the listbox based on push notification and scroll toward the bottom. The issue is that each time it refreshes, I see all the records flashes from top to bottom for a quick milliseconds. How can make it in a way, where it is seamless similar to the phone text message?

```
    private void getJSONObject(string jsonString)
    {

        if (jsonString != null && jsonString != "")
        {

            JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
            JArray a1 = (JArray)o["a1"];    
            JArray a2 = (JArray)o["a2"];    
            JArray a3 = (JArray)o["a3"];   
            JArray a4 = (JArray)o["a4"];  

            //G.msgBox("1st hit");

            //run the following if data exists
            if(a1.Count>0){

                String thisMessage;

                String thisLastTimestamp = (string)a4[a4.Count - 1];

                //G.msgBox("inside a1.count but outside if logic");

                if (lastTimestamp != thisLastTimestamp && isUserTyping == false)
                {
                    IMChatData.removeElements();

                    lastTimestamp = thisLastTimestamp;

                    for (int i = 0; i < a1.Count; i++)
                    {
                        thisMessage = HttpUtility.UrlDecode((string)a2[i]);

                        thisMessage = thisMessage.Replace("`", "'");

                        IMChatData.addElements(
                            (string)a1[i],
                            thisMessage,
                            (string)a3[i],
                            (string)a4[i]
                        );

                    }

                    //lvIMChat.ItemsSource = null;
                    lvIMChat.ItemsSource = IMChatData.collection;

                    //set scroll toward bottom after sending message 
                    lvIMChat.ScrollIntoView(lvIMChat.Items[a1.Count - 1]);
                    lvIMChat.Focus();
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you keep setting your data source with this line `lvIMChat.ItemsSource = IMChatData.collection`.  You shouldn't need to do this.  Set your source once and update the underlying data.

I'm not sure what your collection type is, but I would suggest using `ObservableCollection<T>`.  This will automatically notify the `ListBox` when content changes.

Comment: I don't see BeginUpdate for Listbox in Windows Phone 8?

Comment: I also tried setting the itemsSource once and it doesn't seem to refresh the next time. I think I got a workaround, but not sure if it's the best way of doing it. I've added lvIMChat.UpdateLayout(); toward the end of the code and it seems to stop that flickering issue. I guess UpdateLayout() is the compact .net version of the BeginUpdate() you mentioned earlier.

Comment: @amarankes It's likely not refreshing because your collection doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the control when content changes.  That's why I suggest using `ObservableCollection<T>`.